# Property Name and need its value

Tags: c#, properties

I have a name of a property and need to find its value within a Class, what is the fastest way of getting to this value?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am making the assumption that you have the name of the property in runtime; not while coding...

Let's assume your class is called TheClass and it has a property called TheProperty:

```
object GetThePropertyValue(object instance)
{
    Type type = instance.GetType();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("TheProperty");
    return propertyInfo.GetValue(instance, null);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Note that the function need not have a parameter of a specific type however. `object instance` would do just fine, I believe.

Comment: @Noldorin: you are right about the input parameter; updated the code :o)

Comment: Perfect, I've just added the PropertName in the parameters so you can return any propertyname

Comment: I've come across this many times in two different languages and today I am going to become a Reflection expert! It is the answer!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you have the name of the property as a string. In this case, you need to use a bit of reflection to fetch the property value. In the example below the object containing the property is called `obj`.

```
var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName");
var propValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in speed at **runtime** rather than development, have a look at Jon Skeet's [Making reflection fly and exploring delegates](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the name of the property. If it is a nullable property (e.g. int ? property) use property.Value.

Comment: The down vote was not fair because the question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime you can use reflection to get the value of the property.

Two caveats:

- Obfuscation: An obfuscator may change
  the name of the property, which
  will break this functionality.
- Refactoring: Using reflection in this
  manner makes the code more difficult
  to refactor.  If you change the name
  of the property, you may have to
  search for instances where you use
  reflection to get the property value
  based upon name.