# How to get a ViewModel entity by using the name from a string value?

Tags: c#, class, entity, action, viewmodel

so say I have a ViewModel called

> SampleViewModel

Which contains 3 entities called

> entityOne
>
> entityTwo
>
> entityThree

Now I have an action in a controller action that looks a little bit like this

```
public ActionResult TestAction(string Destination)
{
     SampleViewModel sampleViewModel = new SampleViewModel();
}
```

Now I want to be able to select a particular entity depending on what the string "Destination" is set as.  Destination will always be rather set as "entityOne", "entityTwo" or "entityThree".  So basically I want to call

```
sampleViewModel.entityOne
```

if the string contains "entityOne".

so in affect I am saying

```
sampleViewModel.Destination //Where destination is equal to the one entity in the ViewModel
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can achieve this using reflection. Here's a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034826/using-strings-to-select-object-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Reflection to get, assume you have class `Entity` in here:

```
var entity = (Entity) typeof (SampleViewModel)
                             .GetProperty(Destination)
                             .GetValue(sampleViewModel);
```

Comment: This isnt working for me, I do actually have a list of one entity in my view model, could that cause a problem.  It says No Overload for Method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Ben: seems you are working on .NET 4.0, you can use `GetValue(sampleViewModel, null)` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reflection. For example, if etity is some property you can do the following to get its value:

```
public ActionResult TestAction(string Destination)
{
     SampleViewModel sampleViewModel = new SampleViewModel();
     var value = typeof(SampleViewModel).GetProperty(Destination).GetValue(sampleViewModel);
}
```

Just make sure to handle exceptions properly.